# Need to construct sentence from SQL Table or with Linq and c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following table and I need to run a select query which will give me the bellow sentence. I tried in SQL and I did some queries in c# LINQ but I am failing.

```
CREATE TABLE #proba
(
    leftC int,
    topC int,
    val varchar (MAX)
)

insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(851, 1684, 'Superb')
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(957, 1686, 'Premium') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1105, 1684, 'Update')
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1225, 1684, 'Subscription') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1424, 1684, 'Renewal') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(851, 1730, 'End') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(917, 1732, 'User') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(996, 1730, 'Name:John') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1193, 1730, 'Johnson') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1354, 1730, 'End') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(1420, 1732, 'User') 
insert into #proba(leftC,topC,val) values(851, 1776, 'Email: joe@gmail.com')

select * from #proba order by leftC
drop table #proba
--Sentence that I need to get when ordering the table properly
--Superb Premium Update Subscribtion Renewal End User Name: John Johnson End User Email: joe@gmail.com
```

[image]

In c# language I keep a List collection and run Linq but I am also not able to construct the right sentence.

```
var sorted = obj.Where(xx => xx.top <= 1684 + 20).OrderBy(x => x.left).ThenBy(y => y.top).ToList();
var excluded = obj.Where(xx => xx.top >= firstTop + 20).OrderBy(x => x.left).ThenBy(y => y.top).ToList();
```

I loop through the collection and still not making it. This is what I get.

**Superb Premium Update Subscription Renewal End Email: joe@gmail.com User Name:John Johnson End User**

Comment: I think you have your order statements reversed, you want it ordered by TopC then by LeftC.

Answer (score 0):

ok, SQL query is easy

```
select * from #proba order by leftC
```

[image]

c# Linq version too.

```
var sorted = obj.Where(xx => xx.left < xx.top).ToList();
```

Thank you guys for your attention.